# encrypting password and saving them to database

Tags: hash, password-protection, password-encryption

I have recently implemented hashing in my website. I have a problem. Earlier i was saving password as simple plain text. Now onwards i am saving password as hashed entry .
What should i do with that old plain text entry. Due to being large database it is not possible to convert old data one by one to hashed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be 2 approach

1. After login save password as hash, so when any user gets logged his password will be saved automatically into DB.
   This approach is ok if you don't have pressure about have cleared password in DB.
2. Create a program, that will upgrade clear password in DB.
   This is a risky approach as you need to play around with Id's and to make sure hashed password are not hashed back again.